# Closing all threads when Tkinter window is closed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, paramiko

The Problem: Need the program to close completely when the Tkinter window is closed (click in X)

When closing the Tkinter window ***before the paramiko SSH connection gets stablished*** the program ends.

1- IF Paramiko connection gets established, closing the Tkinter window wont close the program. But entering anything and pressing enter will close the program.

It seems like the paramiko thread never ends.

How can I close the paramik function thread after a connection is stablished??? What am I doing wrong???

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox

#Paramiko Imports
from paramiko import client
from paramiko.py3compat import input
import concurrent.futures # uses the tHread pool executor 
import paramiko
from paramiko.py3compat import u
import threading, sys, traceback

#flag variable
ON = 1
# GUI Function 
def gui():
    global root
    root = Tk() 
    root.title(" MY Gui") 
    root.geometry("1050x590") 
    # Create the canvas
    my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=1050, height=590)
    my_canvas.pack()

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing_main)
    root.mainloop()

def on_closing_main():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to close the main window?"):
        global ON
        ON = 0
        root.destroy()


def paramik():
    # needed parameters for connection    
    port = 22
    hostname = 'beaglebone'
    username = 'debian'
    password = 'pass'
   
    global chan
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
    print("*** Connecting...")
    client.connect(hostname, port, username, password)

    chan = client.invoke_shell()
    print(repr(client.get_transport()))
    chan.send('python3 a.py\n')
    print("*** SSH Connection to BB_AI stablished!\n")

    ##########################################################
    def writeall(sock):
        
        while True:
            data = sock.recv(9999).decode('utf8')
            if not data or not ON:
                sys.stdout.write("\r\n*** EOF ***\r\n\r\n")
                sys.stdout.flush()
                chan.close()
                client.close()
                break
         
                
            # write to console
            print(data, end= '\r', flush= True)

        # This exits the program when the Tkinter window is closed as long
        # as the connection doesn't go through in paramiko
        if not ON:
            return 'Exiting'

    writer = threading.Thread(target=writeall, args=(chan,))
    writer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            d = sys.stdin.read(1)
            if not d:
                break
            # If  after  paramiko stablishes a connection the Tkinter window 
            # is closed then the paramik function thread dosnt seem to end so entering 
            # anthing in console will terminate the Program

            # Needed to terminate as soon as the Tkinter window x is clicked!! 
            if not ON:
                return 'Done'
            chan.send(d)
    except EOFError:
        pass

    chan.close()
    client.close()
    

def main():      
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        
        t1 = executor.submit(paramik)
        
        print(t1.result(), end= '\r\n', flush=True)
        
        if t1.done():
            executor._threads.clear()
            concurrent.futures.thread._threads_queues.clear()
            sys.exit()
            
              

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

Comment: I think you need to call `break` in the `if not ON:` block inside `writeall()` function.

Comment: Hi @acw1668 I tried that before with no luck, the brake will happen after the if not ON: inside if not data since clien and chan will be closed!

Comment: ok, I can only suggest not running gui in a thread, just run it as normal so the other functions run in seperate threads, that way exiting the main thread (the one with gui) will kill all child processes

Comment: @Matiiss thank you for your comment I will try your suggestion, I feel thought that since gui's root.mainloop() will get stuck in a loop, therefore the threading between gui and paramik functions was needed but will definitely let you know if it works calling the gui function not in a thread !!!

Comment: I mean it will run in a loop but since the other processes will be on another thread they will not be affected by that loop

Comment: @Matiiss I just tried your suggestion. Just commented the thread for the gui function and added a call to the gui function after:```
        
        t3 = executor.submit(closing_all)```, while gui and paramik can run without needed to be threaded at the same time, still the program doesn't terminate . Please do you have another idea ??

Comment: @Matiss it seems like the paramik function never finishes because if I type something in the console paramik function tries to read it ending in an error because of course the channel and the client are closed

Comment: maybe add `gui()` before `with`

Comment: @Matiiss I have updated the question since I got the program to close before the SSH connection gets established , after that the paramik function thread seems to not close

Comment: ok, my only idea is to just use `threading` instead of `pool`

Comment: I tried adding the function call to gui() before with but root.mainloop() takes over and then the paramik function never gets executed

Comment: @Matiiss I'll try that !! I really appreciate your help for helping me  with this weird threading nightmare

Comment: @Matiiss No luck with just using threading. I con close the program if I type something in the keyboard . It seems that the paramik function thread still running but as soon as sys.stdin.read(1) gets something , it breaks and goes into the return and the program ends

Comment: If only I could automate the sys.stdin to trigger that while loop inside the paramik function thread.

Comment: @Matiiss I found the problem, is the while True loop that holds the sys.stdin.read(1). Commenting this loop as soon as I close the Tkinter window the program ends !!! How can I end this while True loop  when closing the Tkinter window???

Comment: I guess You could put a condition like `running = True` and after `.mainloop` put `condition = False` or sth like that or maybe You have to call a function that will set it to false or sth like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `while True:` in `def writeall(sock):` you could use an internal bool variable, for instance `while not self._stop:`. Then, write in `def gui():` simply

```
self._stop = False
root.mainloop()
self._stop = True
```